# Android : spinner next index exit after last item

Tags: android

I have implemented a spinner that everytime when I click a button the next item will be selected. But my goal is when the last item is selected the activity should intent in the previous activity. Here is my code so far. I hope someone can help my problem

```
public void spinNext() {
    int nextIndex = spinStudent.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
    if (nextIndex < studentList.size()) {
        spinStudent.setSelection(nextIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your question clear

Comment: @Jas I edited my question sir

Comment: What button are you talking about?

Comment: @Jas A button that trigger the spinner to select the next item in the spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `nextIndex` reaches to last item call `finish()`.

Do this

```
public void spinNext() {
    int nextIndex = spinStudent.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
    if (nextIndex < studentList.size()) {
        spinStudent.setSelection(nextIndex);  
    }
    else if(nextIndex == studentList.size()){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir it works but the activity is exiting in the second last item

Comment: Do you start `nextIndex` from 1?

Comment: uhmm Im not sure sir, :(

Comment: you must have assigned 1 to `nextIndex` somewhere like `nextIndex = 1`. Change 1 to 0.

Comment: If you can't find it then let me know. I will update my answer to match your needs.

Comment: this one sir? ->`int nextIndex = spinStudent.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int spinSize = spinStudent.getCount();

    if(spinStudent.getSelectedItemPosition() == (spinSize -1))
    { 
    finish();
    }
```